# html with value from function

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch

Im really new to this java script and Sencha touch so sorry if this question is simple but I didn't find a way to do this.

I have a function that returns a value .
now I want to display the value from the function inside an html line.

how im calling this function from html element? how I show the value?

```
config: {
        title: 'Me',
        iconCls: 'user',
        //layout: 'fit',
        /* create a title bar for the tab panel */
        items: [
            {
            docked: 'top',
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'Singers'
        },
            {
            html: [ 
                        '<h1>Hi!! ' + this.setName +'</h1>'
                    ].join("")

    }
        ], 

},
setName: function (val) {
    var store =Ext.getStore('user');
    var last =  st.last('user');
    return val=(last.get('user'));
}
});
```

Comment: Add a [handler](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/demos/Ext.Button.handler.1/) to your button.

Comment: but I want this to appear in the html... nothing with the button

Comment: just to show Hello + (the return value)

Comment: Well u have to invoke the function. Try `this.setName()` instead of `... + this.setName ...`

Comment: @DarkBee tried its not working

Comment: `return val=(last.get('user'));'` -> `return last.get('user')`

Comment: @DarkBee no still not working :( got -Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'setName'

Comment: Move the setName function outside config. Its no problem u move your code logic out of the layout. This way u can seperate logic from layout

Answer (score 0):

You could use the itemId property to reference the component and then update its html property via the initialise listener.

For example:

```
config: {
         title: 'Me',
        iconCls: 'user',
        //layout: 'fit',
        /* create a title bar for the tab panel */
        items: [
            {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Singers'
            },
            {
              itemId:'htmlContainer', //use itemIds like div ids
              xtype:'container',
              html: ''
           }
        ], 

        /**
         * @cfg listeners
         * Parent Component listeners go here. 
         * Check sencha touch doc for more information and other available events.
         */
        listeners:{
            initialize: 'onInitialise'
        }

},

onInitialise: function()
{
        //set the html config item here
        var c = this.down('#htmlContainer');
        c.setHtml(this.setName());
},
setName: function (val) {
    ....
}
```